# RegEx for matching temperatures (°c)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I would like to get all temperature/temperature ranges with and without spaces in between them. For now, I am able to get those without spaces in between them using:

```
re.findall(r'[0-9°c-]+', text)
```

[image]

What would I need to add to the regex such that I can get the ones with spaces between them properly as well? E.g 50 space ° space C should be seen as a whole instead of three pieces.

Comment: Try `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*°\s*(?:\s*-\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*°\s*c)?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is very close. But it is missing the "c" character when I tried it in https://regexr.com/ with the text I mentioned above.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added a c in between: -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*°\s*c(?:\s*-\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*°\s*c)? and now it kind of seems to work. I am not sure for all cases.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add it in the first part. Are the `°` and `c` obligatory? Are they always present?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Here is the weird thing. In the files that I have, Some of them have it and some of them don't (These are results of an OCR). So, I would say that they are optional!

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56042512/3832970) showing how to tweak the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*°\s*c(?:\s*-\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*°\s*c)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mWny88/2).

The pattern consists of a `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*°\s*c` block that is repeated twice (to match an optional range part) and matches negative and fractional temperature values:

- `-?`  - an optional hyphen
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional fractional part
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `°` - the degree symbol
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `c` - `c` char.

The `(?:\s*-\s*<ABOVE_BLOCK>)?` matches 1 or 0 repetitions of a hyphen enclosed with 0+ whitespaces and then the same block as described above.

In Python, it makes sense to build the pattern dynamically:

```
tb = r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*°\s*c'
rx = r'{0}(?:\s*-\s*{0})?'.format(tb)
results = re.findall(rx, s)
```

If `c` is optional replace `\s*c` with `(?:\s*c)?`.

If `°` and `c` are optional replace `\s*°\s*c` with `(?:\s*°\s*c)?` or `(?:\s*°(?:\s*c)?)?`.

Here is the temperature block pattern where the degree symbol and the `c` char are all optional but follow in the same order as before:

```
tb = r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*°(?:\s*c)?)?'
```

Full [Python demo code](https://ideone.com/vs5EUR):

```
import re
s = 'This is some temperature 30° c - 50 ° c  2°c  34.5 °c 30°c - 40 °c and "30° - 40, and -45.5° - -56.5° range' 
tb = r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*°(?:\s*c)?)?'
rx = r'{0}(?:\s*-\s*{0})?'.format(tb)
results = re.findall(rx, s)
print(results)
# => ['30° c - 50 ° c', '2°c', '34.5 °c', '30°c - 40 °c', '30° - 40', '-45.5° - -56.5°']
```

If the degree symbol may go missing and `c` may still be there move the grouping boundary:

```
tb = r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*°)?(?:\s*c)?'
                      ^-------^^-------^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z4hecU/1) and the full [Python code demo](https://ideone.com/zDAr45):

```
import re
s = 'This is some temperature 30° c - 50 ° c  2°c  34.5 °c 30°c - 40 °c and "30° - 40, and -45.5° - -56.5° range 30c - 50 °c" or 30c - 40' 
tb = r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*°)?(?:\s*c)?'
rx = r'{0}(?:\s*-\s*{0})?'.format(tb)
results = re.findall(rx, s)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
['30° c - 50 ° c', '2°c', '34.5 °c', '30°c - 40 °c', '30° - 40', '-45.5° - -56.5°', '30c - 50 °c', '30c - 40']
```

Comment: This is a lot of information and I am thankful for it. But I am getting slightly confused. Let us say the ° and c are always optional. (Sometimes they are there, sometimes they are not). Is there a regex you have shown above that account for all cases. Eg: "30°c - 40 °c and "30° - 40" .

Comment: It should get both of them despite the second one missing c and another missing °

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar If you use the `tb` definition at the bottom of the answer, yes, it will, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mWny88/3) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vs5EUR).

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar I added the full demo to the answer.

Comment: It is amazing how you come up with these so quickly. It is working great! Just one more minor case and it would be perfect for me. Is it possible to make it work for: "30c - 50 °c" or 30c - 40 In this case, c is present but ° is not. I know it can no longer be considered a temperature this way but the OCR sometimes gives me this.

Comment: Then use `tb = r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*°)?(?:\s*c)?'`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z4hecU/1)

Comment: I am speechless. It is working exactly the way I need it now. Very impressive!

Answer (score 2):

Try using this pattern:

```
\d+°c(?:\s*-\d+°c)?
```

Sample script:

```
input = "It is 50°c today.  One range is 30°c-40°c and here is another 10°c -20°c"
matches = re.findall(r'\d+°c(?:\s*-\d+°c)?', input)
print(matches)

['50\xc2\xb0c', '30\xc2\xb0c-40\xc2\xb0c', '10\xc2\xb0c -20\xc2\xb0c']
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answering. But in the sample text: "This is some temperature 30°c-40°c.  50 ° c.  30°c -40°c" ,  50 ° c is not caught. Am I missing something?

Comment: Um...maybe I am...but 50C by itself is not a _range_, it is just a single temperate point of data.

Comment: Yes. But I would like something that would catch both temperature range and temperature by itself. I am new to regex. Would that be extremely hard to do? Should I use 2 separate regex?

Comment: Check the updated answer, which now makes the range optional.

Answer (score 1):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/X8E9FL/1) might help you to do so:

```
(([0-9°c\s]+)(?:-[0-9°]+c))|([0-9°\s]+c)
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24), if you wish to know:

[image]

#### Example Test

```js
const regex = /(([0-9°c\s]+)(?:-[0-9°]+c))|([0-9°\s]+c)/gm;
const str = `This is some temperature 30°c-40°c. 50 ° c. 30°c -40°c`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(([0-9°c\s]+)(?:-[0-9°]+c))|([0-9°\s]+c)"

test_str = "This is some temperature 30°c-40°c. 50 ° c. 30°c -40°c"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without degree symbol:

Regex for Temperature in between 33.0 - 42.0 C:

Regex is "(3[3-9]|4[0-1]{1}).|(4[2-2]{1}).[C|c]"

Note: You before 42.0 and after 33.0 all value will come with .1 to .9 but after 42.0 it will throw message Enter temperature between 33.0-42.0